# Redirect HTTPS request to HTTP (varnish) and then backend server HTTPS

Tags: nginx, varnish

My current configuration is like this :
1. Nginx listening on Port 8080 and 443
2. Varnish listening to port 80

Currently, when requests are made through HTTP they are delivered through the varnish, but when requests are made through HTTPS varnish doesn't deliver them.
My goal is to put varnish between Client and Nginx web server ( or make varnish work with port 443 )

Reading through articles and answer on StackOverflow, I tried to setup reverse proxy 443 to 80 ( or 8080 maybe ?)

I followed these article(s) :

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/09/https-everywhere-with-nginx-varnish-apache/
https://serverfault.com/questions/835887/redirect-http-to-https-using-varnish-4-1

Problem is that when I try to set these up, I get 502 bad request error, and sometimes the default Nginx page.

PS: I'm trying to set this up using virtual server block, not default server.
PS2: I also need to deliver the final web page through HTTPS weather the request made through HTTP or HTTPS ( but I get too many redirects error )
PS3: I'm using Cloudflare

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question to show some of the things you've tried, and the exact result you had. You'll also need to clarify what you mean by your last sentence: do you mean that you want requests for `http://example.com` to redirect to `https://example.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is to sandwich varnish between an entity handling SSL and a back-end server working on port 8080 or whatever you choose.
Here's the traffic flow:

user 443 > front-end proxy for SSL offloading 443 > Varnish 80 > nginx 8080.

Now your options for Front end proxy are:

1.A Load balancer supporting SSL termination / offloading.

2.Nginx or apache working as a proxy to receive traffic on 443 and forward that on port 80 to Varnish.

Error 502 means your Varnish is having issues connecting your backend, please check varnish.vcl